# GitLab CI shell runner not inheriting system environment variables

Tags: php, environment-variables, sh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there a way to get the processes started with GitLab Runner (shell runner) to inherit variables defined in the system environment (`/etc/environment`) when running jobs in the GitLab CI/CD pipeline?

The relevant part of the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
synchronize data:
    stage: synchronize
    only:
        refs:
            - schedules
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - [[ -s /etc/environment && -r /etc/environment ]] && source /etc/environment
        # - printenv|sort
        - echo $APP_ENV
        - php -r "var_dump(getenv('APP_ENV'));"
```

This is the output on the job execution:

```shell
Running with gitlab-runner 11.4.2 (cf91d5e1)
  on <redacted> 9b533a38
Using Shell executor...
Running on <redacted>...
Skipping Git repository setup
Skipping Git checkout
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ [[ -s /etc/environment && -r /etc/environment ]] && source /etc/environment
$ echo $APP_ENV
development
$ php -r "var_dump(getenv('APP_ENV'));"
bool(false)
```

The `echo` only works if I explicitly source the file in, but the PHP still does not pick up the variable.

On the machine, I ran this and the variables are definitely accessible by the `gitlab-runner` user:

```
[@localhost ~]$ sudo -u gitlab-runner -i bash --norc --noprofile  
bash-4.2$ echo $APP_ENV 
development
bash-4.2$ php -r 'var_dump(getenv("APP_ENV"));'
string(11) "development"
```

I've also tried `bash` without `--norc --noprofile` as well as `sh` and they all work from the interactive shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that source doesn't export variables. As detailed in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79077/83146) you could use `set -a` before the `source`.